# Generating configuration files using puppet and foreman

Tags: ruby, puppet, bacula, theforeman

I'm trying to push parameters from foreman to my puppet class to generate configuration file.

Eeach file should be like this:

```
file1
DB_USERNAME=toto
DUMP_TYPE=full
[...]

file2
DB_USERNAME=toto
DUMP_TYPE=full
[...]
```

I define a parameter in Foreman which is an array of hashes

```
bacula_client dumpCfg  [{"techno"=>"oracle", "DB_USERNAME"=>"toto", "DUMP_TYPE"=>"full", ...},
{"techno"=>"mysql", "DB_USERNAME"=>"toto", "DUMP_TYPE"=>"full",    ...}]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like that to generate for instance 2 different config files as I get a 'Ressource title must be a string' when calling dumpdb

```
class bacula_client (

$isDirector    = false,
$backupCrons   = [],
$isHostConcentrator = false,
$dumpCfg = [],

define bacula_client::dumpdb () {

    $techno     = $name['techno']
    $dbusername       = $name['DB_USERNAME']
    $dumptype        = $name['DUMP_TYPE']

    # call a function that generates the files
  } 
 [.....]
}#myclass

bacula_client::dumpdb{$dumpCfg:}
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message says it all.  You're naming a resource using a hash.  Supposed to be string.

Try it this way:

```
define bacula_client::dumpdb ($dumpCfg) {

    $techno     = $dumpCfg['techno']
    $dbusername       = $dumpCfg['DB_USERNAME']
    $dumptype        = $dumpCfg['DUMP_TYPE']

    # call a function that generates the files
  } 


bacula_client::dumpdb{'file1': dumpCfg => $dumpCfg[0] }
bacula_client::dumpdb{'file2': dumpCfg => $dumpCfg[1] }
```

Notice the 'file1' and 'file2'.  Those are the resource names that need to be strings and must be unique.  Data is passed in as a parameter.

Not sure if youre array/hash usage works or not.  Didn't test and I don't pass data around that way very often.

And do yourself a favor and put your define in it's own file, not in the middle of a class.  Will save you headaches later (like the one I have trying to make sense of 400+ line classes with all sorts of fun in them accumulated over the last 2 years).

Edit: grammar

Comment: The main issue with this is that I can't iterate on $dumpCfg in my manifest with a for, for instance, as I don't know the number of arrays in the hash. I have to make bacula_client::dumpdb{'file1': dumpCfg => $dumpCfg[0] } bacula_client::dumpdb{'file2': dumpCfg => $dumpCfg[1] } bacula_client::dumpdb{'file3': dumpCfg => $dumpCfg[2] } etc..